# Failed to push to SD card

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am using windows vista on which I installed android. I created an sd card file(.img extension). When I tried to push a file to it through ddms, it showed that 'Failed to push' . Also I could see that the permission parameter was set as d-----. How to reslove this issue. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Once you started the Emulator from one shell, login to another shell & type

```
adb shell
```

You should see # prompt displayed, this is your device(emulator) shell. Now , type following command at adb shell.

```
mount -o remount rw /sdcard
```

This will now remount /sdcard with rw(read-write) permission & now you can push your files into /sdcard by using following command from your host shell.

```
adb push filename.mp3 /sdcard, where filename.mp3 could be any file that you want to push into Android Emulator.
```

Comment: can u please mention what do u mean my shell. is it the command prompt?can u plz make it more clear as am new to android

Comment: Start your emulator, goto -> command line and type `adb shell`